# Update Column when date in other table is older then today (done) + Insert new row in other table with ID from first table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I update the Table `dbo.Auftrag` if all related columnes from the child table `dbo.Positionen` are outdated with this SQL:

```
UPDATE dbo.Auftrag
SET Status = 5
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM dbo.Positionen
                  WHERE dbo.Positionen.FremdID = dbo.Auftrag.ID
                  AND dbo.Positionen.Lieferdatum >= convert(date, getdate()))
```

Now I want in the same case, if the `Status` is set to `1` that in the table `dbo.Eventlog` a new row will be added with the `ID` from the table `dbo.Auftrag` (from which the Status is changes)

I will insert something like that in the `dbo.Eventlog`:

```
ID     ID_Auftrag      Referenz         Benutzer    [Datum und Uhrzeit]    Ereignis
PK(AI) dbo.Auftrag.ID  dbo.Auftrag.Ref  "BW"        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP      "Set Status"
```

How can I archieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [trigger](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/) as follows

```
CREATE TRIGGER AfterupdateAuftrag
ON dbo.Auftrag
AFTER UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @ID AS INT
DECLARE @STATUS AS INT
DECLARE @Referenz as nvarchar(50)        



SELECT @ID=ID,@STATUS=status,@Referenz=Ref FROM inserted
if @status=5 and  convert(time, GETDATE(), 108) between cast('00:00:00' as time) and cast('00:05:00' as time)
INSERT INTO dbo.Eventlog(ID_Auftrag,Referenz,Benutzer,[Datum und Uhrzeit],Ereignis) VALUES (
@id,@Referenz,'BW',getdate(),'Set Status')

GO
```

Comment: Thanks. One question, when this trigger will tigger? It does only happend, if my posts SQL changes anything

Comment: It happens for every update on table dbo.Auftrag (as written  "ON dbo.Auftrag
AFTER UPDATE"), the insertion into dbo.Eventlog happens only when the status is updated to 1

Comment: Ok thaks you very much, I change the Status to 5 and thats it :)

Comment: You welcome, please make a test as follows: update your table with that status and check if the desired row is insserted into dbo.Eventlog, and let me know if it works

Comment: So I have tested it and it works, but also if the user changes the Status manuell to 5, could we also add the condition that this only happend if the Status is 5 and the time is between 00:00:00 and 00:05:00?

Comment: Yes you can add the codition (and if convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 108) between '00:00:00' and '00:05:00' )

Comment: Also I need to add this? if @status=5 AND convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 108) BETWEEN convert(time, '00:00:00.000') AND convert(time, '00:05:00.000')

Comment: yes, I updated my initial script , please take a look

Comment: The condition becomes (if @status=5 and  convert(time, GETDATE(), 108) between cast('00:00:00' as time) and cast('00:05:00' as time))